# Reversing level to xp formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms

I have written a function to convert a given "level" from a game into the amount of XP required to reach that level. Level $0\to 1$ costs $100$ XP, from then on each level costs $25$ more than the previous

- $0\to 1$ = $100$ XP
- $0\to 2$ = $225$ XP
- $0\to 3$ = $375$ XP

The formula I have to convert level to XP is as follows;

$$\text{XP}=(100 \times \text{level}) + \frac{25 \times (\text{level}^2- \text{level})}{2}$$

I need to calculate the reverse of this, converting XP into the user's current level. How can I convert this into a formula for the level?

Comment: Are there only 4 integer levels from 0 to 3?

Comment: @Gribouillis no that was just for example purposes, the level can go up to any number, but never negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the [correct equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=quadratic+fit&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22quadratic+fit%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22QuadraticFitCalculator%22%2C+%22data2%22%7D+-%3E%22%7B%7B0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C+100%7D%2C%7B2%2C225%7D%7D%22) for XP, which you  can also write as
$$XP=12.5l^2+87.5l$$
where I've replaced level with $l$. To solve for the level obtained with a particular amount of experience, simply rearrange to get $$0=12.5l^2+87.5l-XP$$
From here, you can use the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) to solve for the level.
$$l=\frac{-87.5\pm\sqrt{87.5^2+(50\cdot XP)}}{25}$$
In your case, since you know $XP$ will be positive, the second term  in the numerator will always be positive and $\geq$ the first term in magnitude. Thus, you can ignore the $\pm$ and just use $+$ for your formula.

Answer (score 4):

Let us replace $level$ with $v$, and $xp$ with $p$. Then your formula becomes
$$p=(100\cdot v)+(25\cdot (((v-1)\cdot v)/2))$$
This is a quadratic in $v$, as can be seen by simplifying the right hand side.

$$p=100v+\frac{25}{2}(v^2-v)$$

$$p=\frac{25}{2}v^2-\frac{175}{2}v$$

If we image $p$ as a constant for a moment, we can think of this as a typical quadratic polynomial in $v$, which has a well-known solution.

$$\frac{25}{2}v^2-\frac{175}{2}v-p=0$$

Let $a=\frac{25}{2}$, $b=-\frac{175}{2}$, and $c=-p$, then the previous equation has solutions:

$$v=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

For your purposes, one of these solution won't make sense, the one that will is the one where the $\pm$ is taken to be $+$. If you substitute the give values for $a$, $b$, and $c$ the resulting equation will only contain numbers (some simplification is possible) and $p$ (the input variable for the function you desire). This will work as long as $p>0$ (which from context appears to always be the case).

Comment: One thing to note, if you want the player level as an integer, then you will need to take the floor of the resulting value as for xp values that don't match exactly with player level, you will get a non-integer result.